# How can I escape a string to display two $ characters side by side in a Makefile recipe?

Tags: makefile

In a makefile recipe, I would like to display a string with two '$' side by side and not have them evaluated as the shell's process id #.

example:

```
displaymsg: 
    @echo "Hello World!"
    @echo "One Dollar sign:           $$"
    @echo "Two Dollar signs:          $$ $$"
    @echo "Two Dollar signs together: $$$$"
```

The output I would like to achieve is:

```
Hello World!
One Dollar sign:           $
Two Dollar signs:          $ $
Two Dollar signs together: $$
```

But the last line displays the process id from bash:

```
Hello World!
One Dollar sign:           $
Two Dollar signs:          $ $
Two Dollar signs together: 933
```

Any ideas on how to selectively turn off the evaluation and just print '$$'?

Answer (score 0):

Of course, given enough time I figured out that escaping the first $ does the trick:

```
displaymsg: 
    @echo "Hello World!"
    @echo "One Dollar sign:           $$"
    @echo "Two Dollar signs:          $$ $$"
    @echo "Two Dollar signs together: \$$\$$"
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with make.  If you remove the `@` from your makefile (you should **never** add `@` in your makefile until it's completely working because you're throwing away important information) you'll see what make is passing to the shell and if you try to run that same command at your shell prompt you'll get the same failures, because in addition to being special to make, `$` is also special to the shell.  Thus you have to escape it from the shell as well.

Comment: Your solution will work of course, but a better solution IMO is to always use single quotes instead of double quotes whenever you are writing recipes, unless you WANT to allow the shell to expand shell variables.